# How do I create a fade-in link? delayed link

Tags: javascript, html

I want an image link to appear on my page, but only 10 seconds after the page loads. So there would be a delay.

Answer (score 3):

If jQuery is an option then the following should do the trick. Start by defining the HTML element as you like with `display:none` so it starts hidden.

```
<img id="theImage" style="display:none">
```

Then add in the following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#theImage').fadeIn();
  }, 10000);
});
```

If you need it to work with vanilla Javascript then add the following to your window load function

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('theImage');
    x.removeAttribute('style');
}, 2000);
```

Fiddle with sample: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`, and after 10 seconds, either insert the link, or un-hide it? (Although I'd use jQuery/etc. for basically any DOM manipulation.)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.delayed')
    .hide()
    .delay(10 * 1000)
    .fadeIn();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/wPb3e/)

Comment: can someone make me a simple sample page with this? so i know how to put it together?

Comment: @cetin I added a fiddle link to my answer

Comment: @cetinhakimoglu: http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/wPb3e/  You should learn jQuery; you need to **understand** your code.